# Kubernetes pass ingress hosts value as env to a container

Tags: kubernetes

I have my ingress like

```
my-ingress-prd-com-http    traefik-default myingress.prd.myapp.com   traefik-ingress-controller-default   80   157d
```

Now when I configure my app container in the `helm` I'd like to pass its hosts value as an environment variable. Currently I do it from a configmap like:

```
    environmentVariablesSpec:
      - name: INGRESS_ADDRESS
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: my-config-map
            key: ingress_address
```

but instead I'd like to do something like:

```
    environmentVariablesSpec:
      - name: INGRESS_ADDRESS
        valueFrom:
          ingressRef:   // I KNOW IT DOESN'T EXIST IT'S WHAT I'D LIKE TO ACHIEVE ! 
            name: my-ingress-prd-com-http
            key: hosts
```

Do you know if it's possible to do and how ? Kind regards

Comment: you can leverage maybe `helm get values...` save data to json and pass that value to helm chart...however ingressRef would be hard to pass as the field won't be exist unless you use CRD or so.

Comment: @Clyde Barrow did you solve this?